# Нужно ли добавлять .ui файлы в список исходников cmake?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake, qt-designer

Нужно ли добавлять .ui файлы в список исходников cmake?

То есть писать

```
add_executable(my_target main.cpp main.h main.ui)
```

или

```
add_executable(my_target main.cpp main.h)
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Как уже написали, в `add_executable` указывать `*.ui`-файлы не обязательно.

При включённом `set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)` `cmake` сам [просмотрит](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.13.4/Source/cmQtAutoGeneratorMocUic.cxx#L495) все `*.cpp` файлы на предмет наличия в них `include`'ов вида `ui_*.h` и сам обработает соответствующие `*.ui` файлы. При сборке без [`AUTOUIC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/prop_tgt/AUTOUIC.html#prop_tgt:AUTOUIC) (по каким-либо причинам), `.ui` файл необходимо передать макросу [`qt5_wrap_ui()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html#qt5widgets-macros), который явно создаст команду для сборки `ui_*.h`, а хедер уже сам подтянется по зависимостям к исходнику, который его включает.

С другой стороны это не ошибка, `add_executable` (и прочие) допускают указание в списке исходников файлы, которые непосредственно не участвуют в сборке; в данном случае они не добавляются в качестве зависимости к конкретной цели. Обычно мотивацией к этому является использование IDE. В этом случае проект для оной, сгенерированный `cmake`, будет включать их в качестве «дополнительных исходников», и они будут отображаться в списке файлов связанных с целью наряду с остальными. Также, человек, поддерживающий проект, может захотеть указать их просто «для себя», чтобы было явно видно при сборке какого файла используется конкретный `ui`.

Comment: Про оффтоп согласен, сносим, однако хотел еще у вас спросить, вы еще помните свой фидошный адрес? или я ошибся про плюсомёт?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, lol, я не настолько стар =), а «плюсомёт» подцепил уже из вторичных источников...

Answer (score 1):

`ui` файлы не нужно перечислять в `add_executable` или `add_library` - это лишено смысла. Эти файлы обрабатываются с помощью `uic`, так что это он должен знать о том, где искать эти файлы (именно искать). Если `ui` файлы находяться в тоже директории, то все норм, а если в другой, то нужно установть опцию:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS "paht/to/uic/files")
```

Answer (score 0):

На сегодняшний день я не слышал о прямой поддержке `.ui` файлов в `add_executable()`. В этой команде перечисляются лишь исходники, которые CMake умеет "собирать" - `.c,.cpp,.h,.o,.asm`.

Файлы `.ui` обрабатываются специальным макросом `qt5_wrap_ui()` из модуля Qt5Widgets. См. [документацию](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html#macro-reference).